# jquery global animation duration

Tags: jquery

I have a page with many jQuery animations, each has it's own duration defined individually.

I want to disable all the animations on mobile devices by setting the duration to 0.

Is there a way to overwrite all the animation durations globally?

something like this:

```
    if (isMobile()) {
$.animation.duration.disable = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set [jQuery.fx.off](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/) to `true`:

```
if (isMobile()) {
    $.fx.off = true;
}
```